# Any possible way for export two ag-grids data to a single excel file?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I have two ag-grids one beneath the other in the same page. Using the ag-grid export option, I can export them separately. But I am looking for any possible way to export both to a single Excel file.

BTW both grids has same number of columns and headings. Unfortunately the requirement is to have two different grid.

Comment: did you find any approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to export the data of two different grids in two different sheets in the same Excel file.

You can extract the content of a single Excel sheet from a grid using the `getSheetDataForExcel` function of the `GridApi` object of the grid options.

Using this function, you can create an array of sheets from different grids, that you can only export using the `exportMultipleSheetsAsExcel` method of the `GridApi` object of one of the grids, specifying the `data` property of the configuration object in input.

For instance, let's say that you have two grid options objets for the two different grids, `gridOptions1` and `gridOptions2`. One write a function that handles the Excel export including something like this:

```
const spreadsheets = [
    gridOptions1.api.getSheetDataForExcel(),
    gridOptions2.api.getSheetDataForExcel()
];

gridOptions1.api.exportMultipleSheetsAsExcel({
    data: spreadsheets,
});
```

You can even tweak the sheets or file name by passing a configuration object to the grid api method.

Let's say for instance that the exported file name should be **CombinedSpreadSheets.xlsx** and the two different sheets should be named **FirstGridSheet** and **SecondGridSheet** respectively; one can modify the previous code to specify this:

```
const spreadsheets = [
    gridOptions1.api.getSheetDataForExcel({
        sheetName: "FirstGridSheet",
    }),
    gridOptions2.api.getSheetDataForExcel({
        sheetName: "SecondGridSheet",
    })
];

gridOptions1.api.exportMultipleSheetsAsExcel({
    data: spreadsheets,
    fileName: "CombinedSpreadSheets"
});
```

The complete guide to create more than one sheets in the same Excel file can be found [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/excel-export-multiple-sheets/).